# Reverse order of related discussions on proposals

Tags: bug, status-completed, area-51

The discussion questions on the proposal site on Area 51 are ordered so that the oldest discussion is at the top, and the newest discussion at the bottom. This means that if there are more than 5 discussions for a proposal, one has to first click on "show more discussions" to see the most recently edited discussion.

I would propose to just reverse the order, so that the newest discussion is displayed on top.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Good find. We should have been using `OrderByDescending`, not `OrderBy`. It's fixed now, thanks.